# How do I correctly define the type for a proxy wrapping a 3rd party class?

Tags: typescript, proxy

I wrote a wrapper for Firestore's Query class by wrapping it into a Proxy. My proxy does basically 2 things:

1. If you call a function on it that exists on the Query class then my proxy forwards your function call to the Query class.

   - Then if the Query class returns another instance of itself (e.g. when you called `.where()`), my proxy does not return that Query instance, but instead my proxy just wraps that Query instance in another proxy.
   - However if the return type is not another instance of Query (e.g. when you called `.onSnapshot()`), then the result is transparently given back to the caller of the method, without any wrapping happening.
2. My proxy adds a few more methods of my own that I like to have handy.

My first attempt was to write the type definition as follows:

```js
interface MyInterface { /* this contains my own methods */ }
type Store = MyInterface & FirebaseFirestore.Query
```

This works only in the sense that I when I call a query-method on my store that typescript understand that that method is available. But of course this doesn't make clear to typescript that all the query method's return types would be wrapped into another `Store` type. How can I communicate that to typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
interface Snapshot {}

interface Helper {}

interface Query {
  where(a: number): Query;
  onSnapshot(): Snapshot;
}

type ProxyWrapper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...a: any) => T
    ? (...a: Parameters<T[K]>) => ProxyWrapper<T>
    : T[K]
};

interface ProxyExt {
  newMethod(): Helper;
}

let proxy: ProxyWrapper<Query> & ProxyExt;

proxy.onSnapshot(); // Snapshot
proxy.where(2); // Proxy<Query>
proxy.newMethod(); // Helper
```